# Absolute Difference

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the absolute difference of the given list of elements and then want to add the difference value. I am able to fetch the value but I am unable to add the values. 
Following Steps has been tried:
Note: Here I am getting absoluteValue as [1],[1],[0],[1]. Here I tried adding all the absoluteValues and make a single list, but I was unable to. Please help me to understand how can I add all the values in a single list. I

```
n = 5
a = [1,2,3,3,4]
z = len(a)
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    num = a[i] - a[i + 1]
    absoluteValue = [abs(num)]
```

Comment: what is the expected output for the example you gave?

Comment: _Here I tried adding all the absoluteValues and make a single list, but I was unable to._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: `absoluteValue = [abs(a[x] - a[x+1]) for x in range(len(a)-1)]`

Comment: You don't need `z = len(a)`, you never used this var

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the difference to a list.

```
n = 5
a = [1,2,3,3,4]
z = len(a)
absoluteValue = []
for i in range(z - 1):
    num = a[i] - a[i + 1]
    absoluteValue.append(abs(num))
```

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, wouldn't this also work, and save the faff of `range(len)...`: `for i, j in zip(a, a[1:])`?  And by effect, simplify the following line as well, to:  `num = i - j`